# What is the Purpose of Making a Copy of Schema

Tags: mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema, database

I am new to Dbs and currently learning my way through MongoDb & Mongoose.

Referencing this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), I do not understand what is the purpose of line:

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

As per the documentation on the very page linked, we are creating a copy of the schema. Why are we doing that? What is the purpose of creating a 'copy' of model?

Secondly, is it fair to say that, again referencing the above code, the first argument `Tank` is a standard document within the collection `tanks`?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference so I assume that Mongoose will copy the schema to ensure that you can't programmatically modify the schema after the model has been created.

The first argument, **'Tank'** in this case, is the model name/identifier and Mongoose will use the plural form to create a collection in the database. You can use any name that you want but it should be meaningful.

For **mongoose.model('Tank', schema)**, Mongoose will create a collection with the name **tanks**.

Note: You can choose your own collection name using the third argument:

```
mongoose.model('Tank', schema, 'custom')
```